# Determine the Base Current Amplification factor using Ltspice

Tags: transistors, resistance, base

I'm trying to calculate the resistances of my circuit but I'm stuck because I'm missing the B value and don't know how to find it out .
I want to calculate the resistors with which I can determine the current amplification factors B of the transistor 2N3055 (in common emitter circuit) at IC = 200 mA and at IC = 1 A (UCE ≈ 15 V)

This is my circuit :
[image]

To calculate the resistances R1 :
I would need to calculate either B or IB and the problem here I don't have both values

$$ RV1 = B(V1-UBE)/IC $$ or $$RV1 =  (V1-UBE) / IB $$

R2 here is easy to calculate since I have the value of UCE = 15 V which make UR2 = 15 V for both IC_1 = 200 ma and IC_2 = 1 A
Which makes
R2_1 = 15 ohm
and
R2_2 = 75 ohm

The problem here stays with R1 because I'm missing B/IB values . Is there somehow a way with the use of LTSPICE that can get me the B value of 2N3055 transistor or should I just guess it ?
I checked the Data sheet shown in Ltspice but it was unclear there .
This is what I found
[image]

Comment: B is called Beta and it's on that datasheet. Then using those formulae you can get to Ib.

Comment: So it's 100 here in both Ic cases ?

Comment: Read the fantastic data sheet.

Comment: @Gaston That's NOT a datasheet in LTspice. That's a help page!! A help page tells you NOTHING at all about any specific device. Instead, it just shows you what the defaults are. The defaults are "mostly useless" when considering specific devices. In particular, a reasonable model for the 2N3055 model won't show 100 for Bf. That's for sure. (In LTspice I see: .model 2N3055 NPN(Bf=73 Br=2.66 Rb=.81 Rc=.0856 Re=.000856 CJC=1000P PC=.75 MC=.33 Tr=.5703U Is=2.37E-8 CJE=415P PE=.75 ME=.5 TF=99.52N NE=1.26 IK=1 Vceo=60 Icrating=10 mfg=STMicro) .)

Comment: Unless you've got better information. Since no variation is Beta is shown, and the Early voltage is infinite this is a very simplified transistor but if that's what you are given for your exercise, it must be what they intend you to use.  For a 3055, both those currents are "small signal".

Comment: @Gaston That model in LTspice is terrible, too. No Early Effect is listed. Here's a model that dates back to the early 1990's from TI (from an ORCAD database): .model 2N3055 NPN(Is=974.4f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=50 Bf=99.49 Ne=1.941 Ise=902.5p Ikf=4.029 Xtb=1.5 Br=2.949 Nc=2 Isc=0 Ikr=0 Rc=.1 Cjc=276p Vjc=.75 Mjc=.3333 Fc=.5 Cje=569.1p Vje=.75 Mje=.3333 Tr=971.7n Tf=39.11n Itf=20 Vtf=10 Xtf=2 Rb=.1) It's probably a little more accurate and useful.

Comment: As said already by others transistor beta is not constant and can easily vary tens of percents between individuals of the same type and depends on how much there's already current. Datasheets often guarantee only the minimum value of beta. It's a part of the circuit design art to make the variation of beta affecting little enough. Your circuit does not utilize those tricks, it's very sensitive. It can still work if the resistor R1 is selected for a certain transistor individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jameco's 2N3055 sales website](https://www.jameco.com/z/2N3055-Major-Brands-Transistor-2N3055-NPN-Power-Bi-Polar-Expitaxial-Base_38308.html) lists a number of different datasheets for the 2N3055. In addition to those, there is also the [NTE datasheet for the 2N3055](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/original/2N3055.pdf).

From those, find the following minimum values for \$\beta\$ (\$h_\text{FE}\$):

$$\begin{align*}
\text{2N3055}\left\{
{\begin{array}{rl}
\text{TI:}&15 @ 1\,\text{A}\\
\text{ST:}&20@4\,\text{A}\\
\text{OnSemi:}&20@4\,\text{A}\\
\text{Motorola:}&20@4\,\text{A}\\
\text{Central:}&20@4\,\text{A}\\
\text{NTE:}&20@4\,\text{A}
\end{array}}
\right.
\end{align*}$$

I'd gather from the above that most modern 2N3055's will have \$\beta\ge 20\$ for all your cases. But just to be safe, let's go with the **TI** value of \$\beta=15\$. I do think that you could rely on this, today.

Given the other specification for the voltage drop across the collector resistor, you know the BJT will NOT be saturated. So, this means you don't need to worry about that issue. Therefore, your base current will be either \$I_\text{B}=\frac{1\:\text{A}}{15}\approx 67\:\text{mA}\$ or else \$I_\text{B}=\frac{200\:\text{mA}}{15}\approx 13.5\:\text{mA}\$.

The value for \$V_\text{BE}\$ will vary. You can, if you wish, go back through all of the datasheets to find out the worst-case value (OnSemi says this is at most \$1.5\:\text{V}\$ at \$I_\text{C}=4\:\text{A}\$.) That will take into account all temperature variations over the operating range as well as voltage drops due to bulk impedances at each lead (base and emitter) for a current that is higher than you need to deal with. So just pick your poison here. Personally, I'd just use \$V_\text{BE}\approx 1\:\text{V}\$ and go with that. But it's your call.

From there you can compute a reasoned value for the base resistor.

Comment: I see thank you ,  very well explained and given the transistor model in Ltspice like you said is 2N3055 NPN(Bf=73 Br=2.66 Rb=.81 Rc=.0856 Re=.000856 CJC=1000P PC=.75 MC=.33 Tr=.5703U Is=2.37E-8 CJE=415P PE=.75 ME=.5 TF=99.52N NE=1.26 IK=1 Vceo=60 Icrating=10 mfg=STMicro) If i'm choosing the value of β from Ltspice then will it be 73 in this case ?

Comment: @Gaston You should design according to the datasheets. Not according to some model parameter in a Spice program. Especially one that is highly suspect because it lacks any spec for **VA**, which is the Early Effect and most certainly is not infinite.

Comment: Okey thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This circuit is very sensitive to variation in beta, so a datasheet value might not be very helpful whether in simulation or in real life.

If you want to determine beta for this particular transistor under the particular conditions of your circuit, then you will need to find the value yourself by experimentation. A datasheet value will only be a rough estimate.

Comment: Experimentation would require a large statistical subsampling to be worth much in design. Better would be to examine the datasheet for absolute minimums and maximums and use those as guides.